# Question about Android View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

First off I'm new to owning an android and trying to develop android apps. I've noticed that sometimes in applications and in the local android apps that sometimes when you a long press or sometimes just tap a menu comes up. This menu isn't like a context menu bc there is no title. Just a white list of options, and in others it seems to be completely custom but once again no Black Bar title on top of it. If anyone knows the name of this view could you let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right `ContextMenus` are shown on long presses only. Everything else you saw is either a `Dialog` or a custom view. You define menus like described in the android developer articles:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

If you want to completely customize some sort of menu you could also just use a `Dialog` and add every view element you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's in fact a context menu... the only difference is that it does not have a title. Take a look at the `registerForContextMenu`.

Comment: So two questions, can you create a context menu without a long press. I thought that was the only way to implement them. Also to customize them do I have to extend a view or are there built in functions for that. For instance if i wanted more than just a text, maybe a text and image on one line in the context menu.

Comment: Yes, you can... take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html